# Determine if one digit is less that another using equality operator

Tags: probability

I have two digits stored on different computers. First computer can calculated different data structures like integers, decimals, strings, arrays and hash tables based on digit stored in it.  First computer can submit calculated data structures to the second computer.  Second computer has its own set of similar data structures calculated from second digit stored in it.  Second computer can compare this data structures with received ones using equality operator (like == from programming languages).   It is possible to decide that comparison was true if any or all data structures were matched.

This digits are basically timestamps like 1482467977 or 1482554377.

Described behavior looks like some kind of filter function. But I don't know which one.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. What is your math question?

Comment: Um.  Have the computers simply leave the digits alone????

Comment: Yes, we don't know the second one before the transfer and after that we can do one equality check on calculated data.